# Pic12f683 only has digital out on pin 2 (GP5)

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I've been trying to get started with the PIC12f683 in order to get familiar with the PIC family of microcontrollers.

I've got it hooked up to a Pickit 3, and talking to my PC, that all seems to work fine.

I've been trying various LED flasher examples from the internet but no matter which example code I try, or what I do with the TRISO or GPIO registers, I only get output on pin 2, none of the other GPIO pins will do anything.

Electrically speaking... Pins 1, 4, 6, 7, and 8 are connected to the Pickit for ICSP. Pins 2, 3, 5, and 7 have LEDs with 220 ohm resistors going from the pin to ground, and pins 1 and 8 are connected to a lithium ion battery (~3.7 v).

This is the code I am using currently.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000 

#include <xc.h>

// BEGIN CONFIG 
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown Out Detect (BOR disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

//END CONFIG 

int main() 
{ 
    TRISIO =0b00000000; //RB0 as Output PIN 
    GPIO = 0b00111111;
    while(1) 
    { 
        GP5=1;
        GP4=1;
        GP0=1;
        GP2=1; 
        __delay_ms(1000); 
        GP5=0;
        GP4=0;
        GP0=0;
        GP2=0;
       __delay_ms(1000); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

I believe the config portion was generated by MPlab, the rest is copied/modified from this instructable: 
https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Blink-an-Led-With-PIC16F886-/
but the results are the same no matter what example code I use. I'm guessing there's a register or configuration variable I've set wrong somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You had to switch your Outputs to digital.

```
int main() 
{ 
    TRISIO =0b00000000;   //RB0 as Output PIN 
    ANSEL = 0;            // all outputs digital !!!!!
    CMCON0 = 0b00000111;  //turn Cin Pins as I/O
    GPIO = 0b00111111;
    while(1) 
    { 
        GP5=1;
        GP4=1;
        GP0=1;
        GP2=1; 
        __delay_ms(1000); 
        GP5=0;
        GP4=0;
        GP0=0;
        GP2=0;
       __delay_ms(1000); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

The outputs GP0 ... GP4 are default analog ones.
And please remember GP3 share the pin with MCLR, so it is an input only pin.

Comment: Hey thanks! This fixed pins 3 and 5. I also had to turn the comparator off by setting CMCON0 = 0b11111111; to get output on Pin 6. And realize I'd never get any output on pin 4 as it's the input only GP3 (why is pin 4 GP3 and pin 3 GP4...).

Comment: (why is pin 4 GP3 and pin 3 GP4...).  You had to ask this to microchip. I hope your code works fine now.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been going nuts trying to figure out why a bsf of the GPIO was making the other pins go low. It's because, by default, they read as zero so the internal read,modify,write is goofed up. Setting CMCON0 fixed everything.